# How to find work item filed against category value using plain java api?

Tags: java, api, rtc, workitem

I am using below code and found filed against category object but there I am not able to find the value. Please help.

```
IProjectAreaHandle projectAreaHandle = workItem.getProjectArea();

                IAttribute someAttribute = workItemClient.findAttribute(projectAreaHandle, IWorkItem.CATEGORY_PROPERTY,
                        monitor);



    IAttributeHandle iAttributeHandle = (IAttributeHandle) someAttribute;
                    IAttribute iAttribute = (IAttribute) repo
                        .itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(
                        iAttributeHandle, IItemManager.DEFAULT ,monitor);

                    Object value = workItem.getValue(iAttribute);
```

Comment: Not sure that is the right code. Search for "(IAttribute) repository" in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/94776/assertionfailedexception-problem-with-getting-the-values-of-attributes: the fetch gets you IAttributes, not WorkItems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will help to find out the filed against attribute value  :

```
 ICategoryHandle iCategoryHandle = workItem.getCategory();
                ICategory iCategory1 = (ICategory) repo
                        .itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(
                                iCategoryHandle, IItemManager.DEFAULT ,monitor);
                return iCategory1.getName();
```

Comment: @VonC Are you aware about change sets, I need to find out the change set attributes using work item Id. Please help

Comment: First, can you find the change set(s) associated to a work item?

Comment: I have implemented below code to get change sets but it returns blank list :
ILinkQueryPage page = fLinkManager.findLinksByTarget("com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set", reference,
    monitor);
  ILinkCollection linkCollection = page.getAllLinksFromHereOn();
  Collection<ILink> links = linkCollection.getLinksById("com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set");

Comment: @VonC here I need you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344229/how-to-locate-change-sets-in-rtc-stream-using-plain-java-api

Comment: I think it would be the first parameter(scope).

Comment: reffered this answer but no luck https://jazz.net/forum/questions/87178/locate-which-streams-a-changeset-is-on-using-rtc-api

Comment: @VonC again I need your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675106/how-to-change-rtc-stream-and-component-ownership-using-plain-java-api