# How to locate change sets in RTC stream using plain java API?

Tags: java, api, rtc

I am using the below code :

```
 List<IChangeSetHandle> changeSetHandle = convertToChangeSetHandles(

change.getItemId().getUuidValue().toString());

IWorkspaceSearchCriteria wsSearchCriteria1 = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
wsSearchCriteria1.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.WORKSPACES);
wsSearchCriteria1.setExactName(connectedStreamNew.getName());
List<IWorkspaceHandle> streamHandleList1 = workspaceManager.findWorkspaces(wsSearchCriteria1,
Integer.MAX_VALUE, monitor);
ILocateChangeSetsSearchCriteria scope = ILocateChangeSetsSearchCriteria.FACTORY
.create(changeSetHandle, streamHandleList1, Collections.EMPTY_LIST, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
IWorkspaceManager workspaceManager1 = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repoCasa);
List<ILocateChangeSetsSearchResult> result = workspaceManager1.locateChangeSets(scope, monitor);
```

But in last line of code I am getting an exception :Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.ibm.team.scm.client.internal.WorkspaceManager.locateChangeSets(WorkspaceManager.java:252).
```

Please help

Comment: @VonC any suggestion?